# Replacing values in pandas dataframe columns by criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given two sample dataframes:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame([('a', 1, 1000), 
                    ('b', 2, 1200), 
                    ('d', 100, 1500)],
                   columns=['L','A','ADA'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame([('a', 1, 2, 1000), 
                    ('b', 2, 100, 1200), 
                    ('d', 100, 2, 1500)], 
                   columns=['L','A','A','ADA'])
```

I would like to replace values in all columns named `A` if the value is greater than `10`.

The snippet

```
df = df0
df.loc[df['A'] > 10, 'A'] = np.nan
```

Works, perfectly, while the same applied to second dataframe do not works

```
df = df1
df.loc[df['A'] > 10, 'A'] = np.nan
```

since `df['A']` returns two columns.

Is there any approach that can handle both cases?

While renaming the column is a option (I'd rather not), that is how the data is formatted (I can't control this), renaming the data in actual code base leads to many issues downhill. I'm looking for a solution that can handle this case.

If have two columns with same name is a issue, what is the reason to pandas accept this?

Comment: You have multiple same column , that is why

Comment: You may be better off renaming your columns.  I can't think of a good reason to have duplicate names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to replace all your `duplicate` columns:

```
In [2405]: df1
Out[2405]: 
   L    A    A   ADA
0  a    1    2  1000
1  b    2  100  1200
2  d  100    2  1500

In [2405]: import numpy as np

In [2406]: df1.A = np.where(df1.A.gt(10), np.nan, df1.A)

In [2407]: df1
Out[2407]: 
   L    A    A   ADA
0  a  1.0  2.0  1000
1  b  2.0  NaN  1200
2  d  NaN  2.0  1500
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to absolutely retain the duplicate column names, then please try the following. Here, we are trying to access the index of the column and then manipulating it.

```
df = df1
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(float)
df.iloc[:,1].values[df.iloc[:,1] > 10] = np.nan
df.iloc[:,2].values[df.iloc[:,2] > 10] = np.nan
```